# generate artificial non-events based on the real events data

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, dplyr, data.table

there
My problem is : I want to generate artificial non-events based on the real events data

```
> events
                 TIME_ LATITUDE LONGITUDE
1  2013-10-15 00:12:32    9.880  124.1167
2  2013-10-25 17:10:19   37.156  144.6611
3  2014-04-11 07:07:23   -6.586  155.0485
4  2014-04-12 20:14:39  -11.270  162.1481
5  2014-04-19 13:28:00   -6.755  155.0241
6  2014-11-15 02:31:41    1.893  126.5217
7  2015-02-27 13:45:05   -7.297  122.5348
8  2015-03-29 23:48:31   -4.729  152.5623
9  2015-05-05 01:44:06   -5.462  151.8751
10 2015-05-07 07:10:19   -7.218  154.5567
11 2015-05-30 11:23:02   27.839  140.4931
12 2015-07-18 02:27:33  -10.401  165.1409
13 2015-07-27 21:41:21   -2.629  138.5277
```

The artificial non-events must meet:

```
1.  Date between 2013/10 and 2015/10, LATITUDE between -26.0 and 43.5 degrees, LONGITUDE between 118.0 and 175.0 degrees.
2.  Date cannot set to the value plus or minus 30 days for each real events.
3.  LATITUDE cannot set to the value plus or minus 5 degrees for each real events.
4.  LONGITUDE cannot set to the value plus or minus 5 degrees for each real events.
```

I can only think a hard way using three loops (Date: 2013/10/01：1：2015/10/01; LATITUDE: -26.0:0.1:43.5; LONGITUDE: 118.0:0.1:175.0) to implement it, but inefficient.

The sample artificial non-events may be like

```
TIME_ LATITUDE LONGITUDE
1  2014-10-15 00:12:32    19.8  130.0
```

So, can you give a efficient solution.

```
> dput(events)
structure(list(TIME_ = structure(c(1381795952.05, 1382721019.71, 
1397200043.13, 1397333679.3, 1397914080.81, 1416018701.72, 1425044705.37, 
1427672911.01, 1430790246.38, 1430982619.59, 1432984982.11, 1437186453.82, 
1438033281.71), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), LATITUDE = c(9.88, 
37.156, -6.586, -11.27, -6.755, 1.893, -7.297, -4.729, -5.462, 
-7.218, 27.839, -10.401, -2.629), LONGITUDE = c(124.1167, 144.6611, 
155.0485, 162.1481, 155.0241, 126.5217, 122.5348, 152.5623, 151.8751, 
154.5567, 140.4931, 165.1409, 138.5277)), .Names = c("TIME_", 
"LATITUDE", "LONGITUDE"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You want to generate events or to select events in your data set?

Comment: what does your 2-4 conditions mean? what is "cannot set"? what is each real event? can you elaborate?

Comment: @ Emmanuel-Lin generate events,thanks

Comment: @minem  generate artificial events, but cannot set ...

Comment: @Pan Can you add an simple example?

Comment: @minem I have added simple example ,thanks

Comment: @Pan still do not get it, maybe you should explain in detail the algorithm you want to implement, or supply the for loop code, so it would be simpler to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to create an artificial data set within given ranges of time, latitude, and longitude which must have certain distances to real observations.

The idea is to create random samples within the given ranges and to remove those samples which are too near to the real observations.

#### Creation of random samples

```
library(lubridate)
n_dummy <- 2e1L
set.seed(123L) # required for reproducible sample data 
dummy <- data.frame(
  rn = seq_len(n_dummy),
  TIME_ = as_datetime(runif(n_dummy, ymd_h("2013-10-01 0"), ymd_h("2015-10-01 0"))),
  LATITUDE = round(runif(n_dummy, -26.0,  43.5), 3),
  LONGITUDE = round(runif(n_dummy, 118.0, 175.0), 3))
test <- data.frame(
  rn = n_dummy + 1L,
  TIME_ = ymd_hms("2014-10-15 00:12:32"),
  LATITUDE = 19.8,
  LONGITUDE = 130.0)
dummy <- rbind(dummy, test)
```

> ```
>    rn               TIME_ LATITUDE LONGITUDE
> 1   1 2014-04-28 22:21:29   35.823   126.140
> 2   2 2015-04-29 11:06:21   22.150   141.629
> 3   3 2014-07-26 13:16:32   18.515   141.582
> 4   4 2015-07-07 14:27:53   43.102   139.024
> 5   5 2015-08-18 12:59:12   19.572   126.689
> 6   6 2013-11-03 06:08:59   23.243   125.912
> 7   7 2014-10-21 12:24:29   11.813   131.283
> 8   8 2015-07-14 11:10:53   15.293   144.560
> 9   9 2014-11-07 13:08:29   -5.903   133.160
> 10 10 2014-08-30 07:53:24  -15.776   166.896
> 11 11 2015-08-30 11:43:12   40.930   120.612
> 12 12 2014-08-27 22:24:51   36.710   143.205
> 13 13 2015-02-07 15:02:15   22.004   163.539
> 14 14 2014-11-23 00:32:13   29.285   124.948
> 15 15 2013-12-15 03:14:25  -24.289   149.974
> 16 16 2015-07-19 20:56:00    7.207   129.772
> 17 17 2014-03-29 15:27:25   26.713   125.269
> 18 18 2013-10-31 16:52:58  -10.960   160.939
> 19 19 2014-05-28 09:10:15   -3.886   169.018
> 20 20 2015-08-28 18:54:14   -9.902   139.344
> ```

#### Remove samples which are too near to real observations

The OP has specified that the artificial events `dummy`

- Date cannot set to the value plus or minus 30 days for each real
  events.
- LATITUDE cannot set to the value plus or minus 5 degrees for
  each real events.
- LONGITUDE cannot set to the value plus or minus 5
  degrees for each real events.

So, we have to remove any dummy data which fall in the above specified "no-go areas". However, it is not fully clear

1. whether the exclusion conditions have to be applied simultaneously removing all dummy points inside a sphere around each real event in the 3 dimensions time, latitude, and longitude or
2. the exclusion conditions have to be applied independently.

For the removal, a *non-equi join* is used with a helper table:

```
library(data.table)
mDT <- setDT(events)[, .(TIM1 = floor_date(TIME_ - days(30), "day"), 
                  TIM2 = ceiling_date(TIME_ + days(30), "day"),
                  LAT1 = LATITUDE - 5, LAT2 = LATITUDE + 5,
                  LON1 = LONGITUDE - 5, LON2 = LONGITUDE + 5)]
```

#### Variant 1

Applying all conditons simultaneously can be implemented as

```
setDT(dummy)
dummy[!mDT[dummy, on = .(TIM1 < TIME_, TIM2 > TIME_, 
                         LAT1 < LATITUDE, LAT2 > LATITUDE, 
                         LON1 < LONGITUDE, LON2 > LONGITUDE), 
           nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn]]
```

#### Variant 2

Remove all rows where conditions are applied independently:

```
setDT(dummy)
dummy[!c(mDT[dummy, on = .(TIM1 < TIME_, TIM2 > TIME_), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn],
         mDT[dummy, on = .(LAT1 < LATITUDE, LAT2 > LATITUDE), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn],
         mDT[dummy, on = .(LON1 < LONGITUDE, LON2 > LONGITUDE), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn])]
```

which returns an empty table. So, all of the dummy data points violate one or the other condition. Even for 1 M randomly sampled points, non is fullfilling the request indicating that the conditions might be too harsh.

Each of the following expressions return row numbers to be excluded:

```
# rows which violate condition on time / date
mDT[setDT(dummy), on = .(TIM1 < TIME_, TIM2 > TIME_), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn]


# rows which violate condition on latitude
mDT[setDT(dummy), on = .(LAT1 < LATITUDE, LAT2 > LATITUDE), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn]

# rows which violate condition on longitude
mDT[setDT(dummy), on = .(LON1 < LONGITUDE, LON2 > LONGITUDE), nomatch = 0L, rn, by = .EACHI][, rn]
```

The row numbers are combined and removed from `dummy`.